# Bootstrap navbar toggle button doens't work

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are some other posts on this subject and I checked many of the proposed solutions but I failed to understand exactly how I should modify the code. I have tried many times and failed both on HTML and JS.

```html
<div class="mainmenu-area">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Product1.html">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="Categories.html">Categories</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The funny thing is that the toggle button seems to work on local but when hosted online it doens't.
Can you please let me know how to fix it?

Michele

Comment: Are you loading the bootstrap libraries with CDN? Or do you host it personally? Have you noticed the HTTP(S) mismatch? Finally, does it work completely locally?

Comment: Not loading bootstrap libraries with CDN. How can I do? I simply hosted the html/css/js code with AWS S3 and cloudfront

Comment: For CDN: It looks like you are using version 3 [v3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#download-cdn) [v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start) [v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start)

Comment: Are all the JS libraries loading properly? You can check by opening your browser's console and looking for errors. Also, if you share a link to your live site we can look for ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you cant go to http from https. You need to change your bootsrap.js link to https

from

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Infact the scripts on all pages were http and not https. Thanks for pointing that out, it makes a lot of sense that after adding the SSL certificate in the distribution the bootstrap needs to be changed to https. Unfortunately though it still seems its not working, just uploaded the updated code in aws and invalidated the current content cached in cloudfront but the toggle still doesn't work. What else do you think it coud be?

Comment: It is working in your url when i open portal from my mobile. You may be in cache in your browser.  push ctrl f5 to hard load page

Comment: I cleared the cache and now it works for me a s well. Thanks! You're awesome